# Using @Output() with dynamically added components

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a shopping list.
It will be made out of two components: `shopping-cart` and `shopped-item`.

The shopping-cart has a button that dynamically adds a new shopped-item in a `<div>`.

The shopped-item after being added can be marked as active or unmarked so I created an EventEmmiter that changes the value marked/unmarked.
But since the component is added dynamically I don't know where to add it in shopping-cart component...

How can I make it work like this:

After the shopped-item is added it appears in an array with marked/unmarked value that changes when it's clicked in the shopped-item component?

Cheers!

**Shopped-item.ts** file:

```
export class ShoppedItemComponent implements OnInit {

  _ref:any;   
  removeObject(){
    this._ref.destroy();
  } 

  @Output() statusChange = new EventEmitter<{status: boolean}>();

  marked;

  unmarkItem () {
    this.marked = !this.marked;
    this.statusChange.emit({status: this.marked});
  }


  constructor() {    
   }

}
```

**Shopping-cart.ts** file:

```
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('boughtItems', { read: ViewContainerRef }) boughtItems: 
    ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  isMarked = [];

  shoppedItemStatus (statusChange: {status: boolean}) {
    this.isMarked.push({
      status: statusChange.status
    })
  }

  addItem() {
    const shoppedItem = 
      this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ShoppedItemComponent);
    const component = this.boughtItems.createComponent(shoppedItem);
    component.instance._ref = component;        
  }

}
```

**Shopping-cart.html** file:

```
  <div #boughtItems>
    <button (click)="addItem()">ADD</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating the components by hand?

I would use a *ngFor in the view

```
<div #boughtItems>
  <button (click)="addItem()">ADD</button>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <app-item-bought xxxx="item" (markToggle)="myFunction(item)"></app-item-bought>
  </div>
</div>
```

where xxxx is a field of your class ShoppedItemComponent decorated with Input('xxxx').
(markToggle) is the name of the emitter in ShoppedItemComponent and myFunction(item) is a function defined in the Shopping-cart that will receive the item that has fired the event.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But what should be in the addItem() method?

Comment: I don't have all the code, but I guess that in Shopping Cart you will have a list of shopped items (the "items" in the *ngFor). In addItem you only have to add the item to the list and the view will refresh smoothly